# Same Birthday Probabilty code Value is not what was expected

Tags: javascript, algorithm

There is a codewars challenge called the [Same Birthday Probabilty](https://www.codewars.com/kata/same-birthday-probability/train/javascript) which challenge is:

> Given n number of people in a room, calculate the probability that any
>   two people in that room have the same birthday (assume 365 days every
>   year = ignore leap year). Answers should be two decimals unless whole
>   (0 or 1) eg 0.05

and I did the folloowing for this challenge:

```
function calculateProbability(n){
var result = 0;
  for(i=1;i<n;i++){
      var total = (365 - i) / 365
      result = result * total 
  }
  return Math.round(result)
}
```

With and without the `Math.round` method but I always get:

> ✘ Value is not what was expected
>   [image]
>
> and that is the only error.

This is what the test cases are

```
Test.expect(calculateProbability(5)==0.03);
Test.expect(calculateProbability(1000)==1);
```

Comment: `var result = 0;` `result = result * total ` => result will always be 0

Comment: 0 x anything always = 0

Comment: Even if you start with `var result = 1;`, the result will be wrong. Start by computing the complementary event, that all have different birthdays. Should contain a binomial coefficient `365 choose n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should change result to `1` since multiplying by `0` always yields zero. The result you are calculating is the complement of the solution, it is the probability that `n` people have different birthdays. Finally you are not rounding your number to two decimals.

```
function calculateProbability(n){
var result = 1;
  for(i=1;i<n;i++){
      var total = (365 - i) / 365
      result = result * total 
  }
  return Math.round((1-result)*100 )/100
}
```